# Python compare and diff custom object

Tags: python, list, object, compare

How can I compare two list of Objects?

This is the definition of Object:

```py
class Form:
    def __init__(self,name, value):
        self.name = name;
        self.value = value;
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name and self.value == other.value;
```

Now I've two different list of this Object "Form". How can I compare that? I've to found:

- equal name and value
- equal name but different value
- different name from first list
- different name from second list

Thank you.

Comment: You can't provide several equality criteria to a single object in Python, wither instances are equal when they name are equal, or instances are equal when both they name and value are equal, but you nca't have both at the same time. So you need to check for them manually.

Comment: Also, you will have to consider the case where lists don't have the same length.

Answer (score 2):

The last 2 options you want to compare are the same, if you are comparing two items and the names are different, you both are different from the other.

```
lst_1 = [Form('a', 1), Form('b', 2), Form('c', 3)]
lst_2 = [Form('a', 1), Form('b', 0), Form('d', 3)]

if len(lst_1) != len(lst_2):
    print("WARNING: lists are of different sizes, checking the first elements")
for a, b in zip(lst_1, lst_2):
    if not isinstance(a, Form) or not isinstance(b, Form):
        raise TypeError
    if a == b:  # Both name and valua are equal
        print("They are the same Form")
    elif a.name == b.name:  # Only names are equal
        print("They have the same name but different value")
    else:  # Names are different
        print("They have different names")
```

Will output:

```
They are the same Form
They have the same name but different value
They have different names
```